# Inno Setup position a custom button relative to existing buttons

Tags: inno-setup

I am aware that is possible to create a custom button on any page and position it using absolute values using the following code:

```
//Create the About button
  AboutButton := TButton.Create(WizardForm);
  AboutButton.Caption := '&About';
  AboutButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
  AboutButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
  AboutButton.Left := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Left + 10;
  AboutButton.Top := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Height + 90;
  AboutButton.OnClick := @AboutButtonClick;
  AboutButton.Parent := WizardForm.NextButton.Parent;
```

The only problem with this is that since it uses absolute values for positioning, if the user has Windows scaling switched on (under Screen Resolution > Make text and other items larger or smaller) and scaling is set to Medium 125%, the buttons then appear out of alignment with the other built-in buttons resulting in a nasty mess. Therefore, is there a way to position any newly created custom buttons in relation to the built-in buttons, so that they always appear in-line and as they were intended? Or is there another solution to this scaling dilemma that I am overlooking?

Comment: Where do you want to place the Button? In the same region where NEXT and CANCEL is?

Comment: Yes, in line with the Next and Cancel buttons. The same space from the left of the window as the Cancel button is from the right of the window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would write it:

```
  AboutButton := TButton.Create(WizardForm);
  AboutButton.Caption := '&About';
  AboutButton.Left := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Left + (WizardForm.ClientWidth - 
   (WizardForm.CancelButton.Left + WizardForm.CancelButton.Width)); 
   // sets Left position from the Page Left 
   // + already scaled gap calculated on the basis of TLama's recommendations
  AboutButton.Width := WizardForm.NextButton.Width;   
   // sets same Width as NextButton
  AboutButton.Top := WizardForm.NextButton.Top;       
   // sets same Top position as NextButton
  AboutButton.Height := WizardForm.NextButton.Height; 
   // sets same Height as NextButton
  AboutButton.OnClick := @AboutButtonClick;
  AboutButton.Parent := WizardForm.NextButton.Parent;
```

Examples:

[96 (Default)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nadtvsp3vs82jt/96_dpi.png?dl=0)

[120 (125%)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gk2nkzbl44mvn9l/120_dpi.png?dl=0)

[144 (150%)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j95c53l2een15g9/144_dpi.png?dl=0)

Comment: If you want to avoid scaling, get the width between the right cancel button edge and the form's right client edge. That is already scaled and more precise than the magical value 10, [`here is how`](http://i.imgur.com/Rfw6CM8.png).

Comment: Thanks @TLama. That has allowed me to also calculate the distance between the Back and Cancel buttons and between the Back and Next buttons.

Comment: Just a note that these linksare no longer valid with the example images.

Comment: @TLama thanks for the idea. I was able to use this principle to calculate the gap between Next / Cancel buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ScaleX()** and **ScaleY()** on all positions/dimensions:

```
  AboutButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
  AboutButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
  AboutButton.Left := ScaleX(WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Left + 10);
  AboutButton.Top := ScaleY(WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Height + 90);
```

This should work properly on all DPIs.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work and the button disappears completely from the Wizard Page. I assume because it is out of range or something.

Comment: @RobertWigley I have just encountered this same issue.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle It's been a long time since I looked at this, but I did get it sorted. Pretty sure that RobeN and TLama suggestions in parallel sorted it for me. If you are still having issues, after that, let me know and will take a look back and try and work out what I did.

Comment: @RobertWigley Resolved (and improved). I was using `ScaleX` in places where I did not need to because the controls were already at the right size (like the canvas width or existing wizard buttons).

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Glad to hear you resolved it. I am pretty sure it was something similar for me too. Just a weird behaviour that wasn't anticipated.

Comment: @RobertWigley The fundamental issue in this answer is that WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Height Is already sized. So you don’t use ScaleX on it again. You use ScaleX for new positions / widths you want to calculate. Existing controls use their properties as-is.